# the code here works perfectly in codeblocks but in codechef IDE it gives SIGTSTP (runtime error and shows a lot of 0s in the output)

Tags: c, loops, scanf

LINK TO QUESTION : https://www.codechef.com/problems/LUCKFOUR

```
#include <stdio.h>     
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int T,ans;
    scanf("%d",&T);

    while(T) {
        int num,count = 0;
        scanf("%d",&num);

        while(num) {
            ans = num % 10;
            num = num/10;
            if( ans == 4) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n",count);
        T--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Runs normally for codeblocks:it takes T first and then takes input from the user and prints the no. of 4s in that input and repeats the process of taking inputs and printing out the no. of 4s T times

Comment: It's probably a TLE. And the codechef online judge is issuing a stop signal to kill the process.

Comment: If you are getting TLE then don't have the computer waste time converting digits from the input into a number and then convert the number back into digits! Input a string.

Comment: @silentPlanet What makes you think that something reported as "SIGTSTP runtime error" is a TLE?

Comment: Your algorithm is not efficient. Just search for `'4'`s inside the *string* read.

Comment: @Yunnosch That's a common reason SIGSTP is signalled on CC platforms. 
But OP pointed out that TLE is not the issue, so the question remains unanswered.
[Job control signals](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html)

Comment: @silentPlanet Ah. Good to know and makes some sense after reading the info you provided. Thanks.

Comment: Ayush, I find silentPlanet's explanation so convincing that I now ask your to explain what makes you think that it is not TLE. In which way can you determine that "solution got accepted and satisfies all conditions" if it then does not run through and does not end in a meaningful result?

Comment: when i ran the code in the ide i saw the error "SIGTSTP" But on submission my code was accepted

Comment: To me it's very unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

I did a little modification in your solution, and it passed. Just pay attention to the constraints, because sometimes `int` can cause an overflow. Take a look:

```
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  long long int T;
  scanf("%lld", &T);

  while(T--) {
    long long int num, count=0;
    int ans;
    scanf("%lld",&num);

    while(num) {
        ans = num % 10;
        num = num/10;
        if( ans == 4) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",count);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

[Submission image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvR4M.png)

Comment: how does long long int make any difference , my question got submitted with a correct answer but gave an error while running in the codechef ide

Comment: Got it. I thought your solution was not accepted because of that. When I'm solving a problem with a constraint like 10⁹, I use `long long int` to avoid overflow issues.